# Planned shutdown of the computer with a custom message

Tags: winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

Is it possible to perform a delayed shutdown of the computer using an API function that displays a "you are about to exit" message, similar to performing a `shutdown /s /t xx /c "xxxxxxxx"` when the shutdown is scheduled for less than a minute?

MSDN's documentation on InitiateSystemShutdown says so:

> If `dwTimeout` is not zero, `InitiateSystemShutdown` displays a dialog
> box on the specified computer. The dialog box displays the name of the
> user who called the function, displays the message specified by the
> `lpMessage` parameter, and prompts the user to log off. The dialog box
> beeps when it is created and remains on top of other windows in the
> system. The dialog box can be moved but not closed. A timer counts
> down the remaining time before a forced shutdown.

It does not so much fit what I am looking for...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdownw ?

Comment: Did [InitiateSystemShutdownEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdownexw) or [InitiateSystemShutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdownw) solve your question?

Comment: @yonni I haven't seen there is an API which can retrieve the shutdown timer or final time.